# Bokeh bar plot: color bars by category

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm tweaking the second example located [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.0/docs/user_guide/charts.html#box-color).

Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.charts import BoxPlot, Bar, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df
output_file("bar.html")
p = Bar(df, values='mpg', label='cyl', color='origin', legend="top_left",
            title="MPG Summary (grouped and shaded by CYL)")
show(p)
```

There are three changes: (1) I used a `Bar` plot, (2) I changed the `color` attribute to a different categorical variable and (3) I added a `legend` attribute.

The problem is between (2) and (3) I believe. More specifically, the legend becomes tuples of the `label` and `color` attributes because they are different - when they are the same, the chart and the legend work properly.

This is a basic feature of `ggplot2` in R and I thought it would work here. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

*bokeh version 0.12.0*

*Update with image:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `bokeh.charts` API, including `Bar` was deprecated and removed in 2017. Since then, much work was done to improved the stable and supported `bokeh.plotting` API, and it it now possible to easily create many kinds of categorical and bar plots. Many examples can be found in the [Handling Categorical Data](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) chapter of the Users Guide.

It's not exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish with your plot. Using the same data, here is a plot of car counts broken down by origin and number of cylinders:

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

# Bokeh categories are strings
df.cyl = [str(x) for x in df.cyl]
df.origin = [str(x) for x in df.origin]

# pivot to wide format
df = df.pivot_table(index='cyl', columns='origin', values='mpg', fill_value=0, aggfunc='count')

p = figure(title="Count by cylinder and origin", x_axis_label="Cylinders",
           x_range=sorted(df.index))
p.y_range.start = 0

p.vbar_stack(df.columns, x='cyl', width=0.9, color=["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"],
             source=df, legend=[value(x) for x in df.columns])

show(p)
```

[image]

For an even higher level, data-centric API that let's you do this with even less code, you might check out [Holoviews](http://holoviews.org/) which is built on top of Bokeh.